# Is it possible to subscribe to a topic in redis using quarkus-redis-client?

Tags: quarkus

After I've read the redis quarkus client documentation, I noticed that there is no mention of how to subscribe to a redis topic using the extension **quarkus-redis-client** and defining a handler to handle the received message.

Does someone have a working example ?

Comment: Did you figure it out? Documentation is really bad.

Comment: @MichelJung I just posted an answer you can check the project that I've created, come back to me if you have more questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a small project to showcase a redis pub/sub using quarkus https://github.com/omarkad2/quarkus-redis-example.

I noticed that there is no API in the quarkus's extension quarkus-redis-client allowing to define subscriber handlers, so I ended up using vertx to register my handlers.

Comment: Wouldn't have figured that out, you made my day! Thank you :)

Comment: Maybe you could add the relevant code to your answer, links could always go offline